# If $f(x,y,t):= u(r) \cos ( \omega t)$, use the multivariable chain rule to obtain an ODE for $u$ from the PDE for $f$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, power-series, mathematical-physics

Let $f(x,y,t) :=u(r)\cos \omega t$, where $r= \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$. Physics tells us the following: For $f(x,y,t)$ to describe a vibrating membrane, with $f(x,y,t)$ telling how high the mem-
brane is above the rest position at point $(x,y)$ and at time $t,f$ must satisfy the condition  $$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = c^{−2} \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial t^2}$$ with $c$
the wave propagation speed in the membrane.

Your job is simply to use the multivariable chain rule and obtain an ODE for $u$
from the partial differential equation for $f$. Compare the ODE so obtained with the Bessel
ODE.

I think that I understand the multivariable chain rule, but I am confused about whether to take the partial derivative of f with respect to $x$ and $y$ or $r$...or if I even need to start from the original function of $f$ or work just from the pde condition given.

Comment: I believe you're meant to exchange the partials of $f$ by the appropriate expression containing the derivative of $u$ (as a function of $r$, naturally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the given pde for $f$ and plug in the form of $f$ that you know.

For example $\partial_{x} f = u'(r) (\partial_x r) \cos \omega t = u'(r) \frac{x}{r} \cos \omega t.$
Do the same to compute $\partial_{xx} f, \partial_{yy} f, \partial_{tt} f$ (the last one is easy since $r$ doesn't depend on $t$!). Once you have all these partial derivatives in terms of $u$, do you see how your original pde turns into an ode for $u$ just by plugging in the expressions in terms of $u$ for $\partial_{xx} f, \partial_{yy} f, \partial_{tt} f$?

Comment: ohhh, that makes much more sense now. So I've gone through all of the calculations of the partial derivatives and now have it in the form of a ode for u, but in calculating the derivatives I now have both r, x and y in the ODE. Is this okay or do i need to rewrite r in terms of x and y?

Comment: And thank you so much, we don't use a specific text in this class, so  I have been combing the internet for the past few hours looking for similar examples and just couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: You need to get rid of the $x,y,t$ in the equation so that it looks like $F(u(r),u'(r),u''(r)) = 0$ which only depends on constants and  $r$